# Line break within a cell of a table

Tags: tables

I need a line break in one of the column headers. I tried using the suggestions from the earlier posts but since the column header is an equation, I couldn't use them. I need the line break in the column header of 4th column as given below :-

[image]

The code i have written is :

```
\begin {table}[h]

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}

\hline

$i$ & $Degree \phi_i$ & $\cos(\phi_i)$ & Product of $\cos(\phi_i)\par K=\prod K_i=\prod\cos(\phi_i)$ \\

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end {table}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always put a tabular inside a tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin {table}[h]

    \begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}

    \hline

    $i$ & Degree $\phi_i$ & $\cos(\phi_i)$ &\begin{tabular}{@{}l} Product of $\cos(\phi_i)$\\$ K=\prod K_i=\prod\cos(\phi_i)$
\end{tabular} \\

    \end{tabular}

    \end{center}

    \end {table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

(Please observe a different usage of dollar signs).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That is exactly what i was looking for. Just one more query what is the function of {@{}1} in the command begin{tabular}{@{}l} ?

Comment: @ShraySharan `@{argument}` adds `argument`  to all colums. It also removes horizontal spacing and this behaviour is expected here (not double value of  `\arraycolsep`).

Comment: @ShraySharan You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a simple left-aligned stack would do.  I also add a vertical buffer above/below the stack to offset the horizontal lines more than the default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin {table}[h]

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}

\hline

$i$ & Degree $\phi_i$ & $\cos(\phi_i)$ & \def\stackalignment{l}
  \addstackgap[2pt]{%
  \stackunder{Product of $\cos(\phi_i)$}{$K=\prod K_i=\prod\cos(\phi_i)$}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end {table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Merely changing the macro `\stackunder` to `\stackanchor` changes the vertical alignment of the stack to a centered configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `makecell` package. It allows for a common formatting in column heads and line breaks in cells. Also your table will look better without vertical lines. The `booktabs` package defines horizontal rules with variable thickness and some vertical padding around these rules. I replaced the `center` environment (which adds vertical spacing around the table) with a simple `\centering` directive. Last, not least, the `siunitx` package is there for a fine formatting of numerical columns.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{ table-format=1.8,table-number-alignment=center}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setcellgapes[t]{3pt}
\setcellgapes[b]{1pt}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\boldmath}
\begin{document}

\begin {table}[h]
\centering\makegapedcells
%\begin{tabular}{|l|S[table-format=2.8]|*{2}{S|}}
%\hline

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.8]*{2}{S}}
  \toprule
  {\thead{$i$}} & {\thead{Degree $\phi_i$}} & {\thead{$\cos(\phi_i)$}} & {\thead{Product of $\cos(\phi_i) $ \\ $K=\prod K_i=\prod\cos(\phi_i)$}} \\
  \midrule
  1 & 45.00000000 & 0.70710700 & 0.70710678 \\
  2 & 26.56505118 & 0.89442700 & 0.63245553 \\
  3 & 14.03624347 & 0.97014300 & 0.60883391 \\
  4 & 7.12501635 & 0.99227800 & 0.60764826 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end {table}

\end{document}
```

[image]